# I have problem with definition of webhook

Tags: python-3.x, discord, webhooks, discord.py

So here's the problem I don't now how to define a webhook message in `if message ==` Here's my code:

```
webhook_urls = ['url1', 'url2]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channels = ["global"]

    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
            return

    if message == DiscordWebhook:
            return

    for word in channels:
            await message.delete()
            response = DiscordWebhook(url=webhook_urls,  content=message.content).execute()
```

It should return the webhook.

Comment: No in edit o forgot to add it there's problem in 'if message == DiscordWebhook:

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the message has a [`webhook_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.webhook_id)

```
if message.webhook_id is not None:
    ...
```